# How to extract data between a date range which has only start and end date values in the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, range, date-range

I have a table with 10+ million records and the structure is as follows -

| Store ID | Item ID | item_active_Date | item_inactive_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY0001 | FMC0001 | 2021-10-30 | 2021-11-30 |
| NY0001 | FMC0002 | 2021-01-10 | 2021-06-14 |
| NY0002 | FMC0003 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-10 |
| NY0002 | FMC0004 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| NY0003 | FMC0005 | 2021-04-01 | 2021-05-30 |
| NY0003 | FMC0006 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-06-24 |
| NY0004 | FMC0007 | 2021-01-02 | Null |

The need is to identify the item_ID's available between a given date range. Only item_active and item_inactive dates are available.

Consider the item_ID's that were available between "2021-06-15" and "2021-11-25". The expected result is as follows (When item_inactive date is not available consider it as today)-

| Store ID | Item ID | item_active_Date | item_inactive_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY0001 | FMC0001 | 2021-10-30 | 2021-11-30 |
| NY0002 | FMC0003 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-09-10 |
| NY0003 | FMC0006 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-06-24 |
| NY0004 | FMC0007 | 2021-01-02 | Null |

Comment: Dates in SQL are stored in the format  YYYY-MM-DD (year-month-day), these are year-day-month.  Did you make a mistake copying the data into your question or is the database actually storing dates this way?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @DaveS. It's my mistake that I have copied the data wrong. Will correct it  now.

Comment: @DaveS Nope dates are not stored in ANY readable format if the datatype is date (or a related datatype). The format you "see" is an artifact of the application you use to display that datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should work, I believe:

```
SELECT item_ID FROM my_table
    WHERE item_active_date <= $endDate
        AND (item_inactive_date IS NULL
            OR item_inactive_date > $startDate);
```

Although you'll want to make sure your SQL engine is interpreting the the values in these inequalities as dates, not strings, since the format your table is using has days between months and years.

Comment: Note to OP - you might need to adjust the logic slightly if your table dates are inclusive or exclusive (most likely the inactive date might be exclusive).

Comment: Fair point @SMor

Comment: Solved the requirement @kagof. Kudos !!!

Answer (score 2):

**The correct way to find overlapping intervals** is to compare one's start with the other's end, and the other's start with the first's end.

This is far more performant than using complex `OR` conditions, as you are doing a straight range lookup. You do have one downside in your setup in that  `item_inactive_date` can be null, so you will need an index on `item_active_Date` instead.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.item_active_Date < '2021-11-25'
  AND (t.item_inactive_date IS NULL OR t.item_inactive_date > '2021-06-15');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=59b04abce70ad58320efb4436b1bf8c3)

You may need to adjust `<` to `<=` etc depending on your desired logic

Comment: This solves the problem @Charlieface !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
SELECT * FROM Sample
WHERE 
  item_active_Date BETWEEN  '2021-06-15' and '2021-11-25' 
 OR item_inactive_date BETWEEN  '2021-06-15' and '2021-11-25' 
 OR item_active_Date IS NULL
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ec082/4)

**UPDATE From Comments**

> Consider the scenario where for an item_id active_date = '2021-06-01'
> and inactive_date = '2021-11-29'. This should also be part of the
> result as the item was 'ACTIVE' between our query date range

if I've got your requirements correctly, it would be very difficult to get the results that are not recorded (or tracked) within the date range (unless if there are other flags or columns can handle that). For instance, if the item were active a day before the given start date, and marked as inactive a day after the end date, it'll not show up in the results, because there are no records of monitoring the items daily activity. Similarly, items were do not have inactive date (supposed they're still active) will have the same issue.

So, to have an accurate results, and make things easier to query, you will need to regenerate the items activities based on their active and inactive dates. So, we need to fill the dates gap first. Take item `FMC0003` as an example, it's active on `2021-09-01` and inactive on '2021-09-10'. We will need to regenerate it to have a record for each date from the active date to the inactive date. So, in our example item `FMC0003` will have 10 records. This will be applied to all records in the table.

Example :

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        [Store ID],
        [Item ID], 
        item_active_Date ,
        ISNULL(item_inactive_date, GETDATE()) item_inactive_date
    FROM Sample s
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        c.[Store ID],
        c.[Item ID], 
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, c.item_active_Date) ,
        c.item_inactive_date
    FROM CTE c
    WHERE 
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, c.item_active_Date) <= c.item_inactive_date 
)
SELECT *
FROM Sample
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM CTE c 
    WHERE c.item_active_Date BETWEEN '2021-06-15' AND '2021-11-25'  
)
ORDER BY [Store ID], [Item ID], item_active_Date
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Thanks @iSR5 for the solution. It works great when the data in active or inactive date column is avaiable. When the item was active before the given range and is inactive after the date range, value is not available.

Comment: @Dhananjayan I see you've chosen an answer, if you still need help with it, please provide a sample for this case scenario, as my solution tight to the sample and expected results that you've provided in your post.

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind gesture. Consider the scenario where for an item_id active_date = '2021-06-01' and inactive_date = '2021-11-29'. This should also be part of the result as the item was 'ACTIVE' between our query date range